# DataFrame row-wise Optimize (Scipy)

Tags: python

I tried a while to look for this, but could not find anything that would solve my issue. This is also my first post, so please be gentle.

I wanted to apply an optimisation algorithm for every row of a DataFrame where I would be taking the static variables from other columns of the DataFrame. I managed to do something that works, but I hoped that there would be a better, more elegant way.

I put together an example to illustrate my problem. I would like an outcome with an array of [2,3,4].

This works (but I don't really like it, especially for larger datasets):

```
Testing = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[2,6],[3,12]],columns=['x','y'])

def test_function(x):
    return (a * x - b)**2

for row in range(len(Testing)):
    a = Testing.loc[row,'x']
    b = Testing.loc[row,'y']
    rest = optimize.minimize_scalar(test_function)
```

But I hoped that there could be something similar to this:

```
Testing = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[2,6],[3,12]],columns=['x','y'])

def test_function(df,z):
    return (df['x'] * z - df['y'])**2
    
Testing['z'] = Testing.apply(optimize.minimize_scalar(test_function))
```

Your help is much appreciated.

Thanks,

B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found a way around it from a different post, I hope this might help someone.

```
Testing = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[2,6],[3,12]],columns=['x','y'])

def test_function(df,z):
    return ((df['x'] * z - df['y'])**2).mean()

z=np.array([1,1,1])

Testing['z'] = optimize.minimize(lambda z: test_function(Testing,z),x0=z, tol=0.0000000001).x
print (Testing)
```